# Parse load multiple PFFile images in single query

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Here is how I load images:

```
func LoadImage(sender:FeedVC, cellId:Int){

    self.currentlyLoading = true
    let query = feed[cellId].fileName

    query.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.feed[cellId].fileImage = UIImage(data:imageData)!
            self.feed[cellId].loading = 2
            self.loadedCount++
            self.currentlyLoading = false
            sender.updateCell(cellId, animation: true)
            self.CheckWhatToLoad(sender)
        } else {
            println("The LoadImage request failed.")
        }
    }
}
```

I run this piece of code for every single image the user loads. Is there a way to load multiple images with only 1 query?

Comment: First question is, are you sure you want to do this?  Do you want to block until all files are loaded?  Typically you would want to display an image as soon as it is available rather than waiting for all of them.

Comment: the pattern of my loading is kind of like this atm: 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8

so at the start i download images one at a time quickly, than as data are downloaded i have free network to load the future images. so yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in Parse you can not do such a thing.

What you can do is

1. Follow [parse blog](http://blog.parse.com/) and  see if they introduce such a thing in
   the future.
2. Parse has recently [open-sourced](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/open-sourcing-our-sdks/) its SDKs and if you wish to spend the
   time, you can commit such a code and hope that they accept it.